# Identify this minifigure

Tags: set-identification, minifigure-identification

I found this minifigure on the street.

Can anyone help me identify what it is and what set is it from?

The hands were not originally grey, they were in the colour of the head.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  What sort of street did you find this minifig on?  Was it near a LEGO convention?

Comment: @chicks Not that I know of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The torso for this figure is [973pb0321c02 Torso Town Vest with Pockets and Striped Tie over White Open Collar Shirt Pattern / White Arms / Yellow Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0321c02&in=M).

[image]

It comes in several minifigures, but none of them are like yours, so I think this is composed of other parts ( a MOC figure) and not directly from a set.

Comment: I see. It seem that there is a high chance that it's [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?M=twn052) as both the hair and the legs match. Any idea where the head might come from?

Comment: The head is  [Minifigure, Head Male Black Eyebrows, Chin Dimple and Lopsided Grin Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626cpb0857&in=M) , it appears in 50 minfigures

Comment: Thanks @Syberion

Comment: How is this correct when the question and image show grey hands?

Comment: @chicks Again, it's a MOC figure. What do you expect?

Comment: I get that it is a MOC and we're not going to find a matching minifig from a set.  I wouldn't expect most people doing MOC's to swap hands to a different color.  The odds seem worse since this was just "found on the street."  I wonder if bricklink doesn't include all of the variants of this part.  It is too bad we can't find the person who made it.

Comment: @chicks The hands were replaced by me when playing with my children. That's what I meant by 'the hands were not originally grey'. How would I know it otherwise? I was not able to replace the hands with the yellow ones when doing the picture, do I decided to add this comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense now.  Sorry for adding any doubts to the answer.  I was just confused.